# MacBook Pro keyboard backlight on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, boot-camp, macbook-pro

Is there any way I can save the keyboard backlight setting under Windows 7? Every time I boot it is on the max setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** The tool mentioned in this answer no longer seems to be available.

There's this tool called PowerPlan which should give you the possibility to disable the keyboard backlight altogether when using Bootcamp and Windows 7. I haven't tried it myself but according to some forum posts it should be working.

Comment: slhck, that link is dead. (For some reason I can't use @ sign to tag people atm.)

Comment: @gosr Yeah, that link turned quite spammy. Sorry, the tool seems to be not available anymore.